# What triggers "Do you want to allow "My app" to use Face ID?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm getting this popup when my app loads as I'm using face id. I'm ok with it loading up but I only want it to load up when im using face id, but right now it's just loading up when I close the splash screen. I was wondering what triggers this pop up to show and where I can decide what point it gets loaded up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` in your `plist`by describing with a String.
Apple Reference is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id)

**Edit**

PO already have done the permission from the plist. This is the one which trigger this alert :

```
Keychain.getGenericPassword()
```

Comment: I've done that but I figured it out so will delete the question. it was because I was getGenericPassword from keychain which triggers it

Comment: I wont delete then